# Unity3d : Coloured Layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been searching for a while now on how to draw a coloured rectangle in `Unity3d` using `tk2d`. What I want is to create a coloured layer without using any sprite, and at some point I will mask this layer to put a hole in it. I want the system to draw a coloured rectangle to save resources. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class StretchSprite : MonoBehaviour
{
    public tk2dCamera UserInterfaceCamera;
    private tk2dSprite _sprite;
    protected void Start()
    {
        _sprite = GetComponent<tk2dSprite>();
    }
    protected void Update()
    {
        if (_sprite)
        {
            _sprite.scale = new Vector3(UserInterfaceCamera.ScreenExtents.height / _sprite.CurrentSprite.GetUntrimmedBounds().size.y,
                UserInterfaceCamera.ScreenExtents.width / _sprite.CurrentSprite.GetUntrimmedBounds().size.x, 1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

i stretch a single black pixel to fill the screen like this to fade the camera...

edit: ya i guess i should not do that each time... just when orientation changes

edit:
"I think the EASIEST way to do this is to create one sprite and change the scale property in the sprite collection editor - for example, if its 1x1, set the scale to 4096x4096 and the sprite will fill your screen. You won't need to change any scale at runtime. The pixels that get clipped won't really cost anything, so that could be a quick way to do this."

http://2dtoolkit.com/forum/index.php/topic,726.msg3479.html#msg3479